# Laravel migrations change a column type from varchar to longText

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I need to change with a migration column type of `$table->string('text');` to a text type, I have tried to do that in a few ways, but none of them worked. Is it possible to do it in one migration? I could I guess drop the column and then create it again with a new type, but I wonder if it is possible to do it in one migration?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you have to drop that column even if you only change its type.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can create a new migration and [change just one column type](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#modifying-columns):

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('sometable', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('text')->change();
    });
}
```

You need to install `doctrine/dbal` to make this work

```sh
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Works with Laravel 5.0+. It does not work with Laravel 4.2.

Comment: do you still need to drop the field? because I am still getting "Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name"  when using your code to change a column.

Comment: @NewbieLearner This feature is available since Laravel 5.0. If you are using Laravel 4.2, this won't work.

Comment: You will only need doctrine/dbal if you're working with SQLite. See more: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns

Answer (score 44):

It's possible to do with a TABLE migration.

As mentioned in other posts, be sure to run `composer require doctrine/dbal` from your project root.

These are set up with:

```
php artisan make:migration alter_table_[yourtablenamehere]_change_[somecolumnname] --table=[yourtablenamehere]
```

from your project root.

From the Documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns

```
class AlterTableSomething extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('column_name')->change();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

According to [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns)

You can do it like

```
Schema::table('yourTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->text('text')->change();
});
```

> be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file

Answer (score 14):

If you get following error using `change()`

> Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL80Platform may not support it.

this means that exists some column (not necessarily changed one) in your table which has enum type. So instead using `change()` you can use following function:

```
public function changeColumnType($table, $column, $newColumnType) {                
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE $table CHANGE $column $column $newColumnType");
}
```

And use it like that: `$this->changeColumnType('sometable','text','TEXT');`

Comment: tytyty for example of how to do the blueprint :)

Answer (score 4):

Following worked for me.

Definitely you need to install **doctrine/dbal** to make this work, using following command in terminal.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Then create migration as mentioned here- https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#generating-migrations

open your migration file and write down below.

```
Schema::table('yourTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('column_name','4294967295')->change();
});
```

As, longText have maximum of 4,294,967,295 character limit, Laravel will automatically change column_name to longText data type.

Answer (score 2):

The previously suggested solutions are good, but what surprises me is that no one mentions the `down()` method, except @Ahmet Firat Kele.
This method is executed when you run the command `php artisan migrate:rollback`, and after its execution, we should have the changes that were in place before running this migration. 
This is crucial!

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('sandbox', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('column_name')->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('sandbox', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('column_name')->change();
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need [doctrine/dbal](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal), that's true.

**BUT, be careful!** *Otherwise you may end up in trouble.*

Here's a safer way

1. Backup your project files!
2. Take a look at your composer.json file to note your PHP version. Let's say you have 7.2.5. Now, search for a compatible version which is [2.13.9](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal#2.13.9) in this case.

[image: Version 2.13.9]

3. If you do not want to mess with other dependencies, make sure you install this package using this command

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require doctrine/dbal "^2.13.9"
```

4. Now we're ready to make changes!

- Generate your migration file

```
php artisan make:migration change_xxx_type_in_yyy_table --table=yyy
```

- Change its content according to your needs

```
// Let's assume we change an integer column's type to string
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('yyy', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('xxx')->change();
  });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
*/
public function down()
{
  Schema::table('yyy', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('xxx')->change();
  });
}
```

- Run your migration

```
php artisan migrate
```